# Hamburger button moves when it is clicked

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my hamburger button. When I on the hamburger button, its' position moves. I want it to stay in the same place when it is clicked.

I posted all my code on jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/rcs7vfte/

```js
const nav           = document.querySelector('nav');
const toggleButton  = document.querySelector('.menu-button');
const links         = document.querySelector('.links');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav--active');
    links.classList.toggle('links--active');
});
```

```html
<nav>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://www.designfreelogoonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/000840-Infinity-logo-maker-Free-infinito-Logo-design-06.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="menu-button">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <ul class="locals">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dining</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="socials">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the vertical button movement is the appearance of the scroll bar after expanding the navbar, we can fix that by forcing the scroll bar to appear even if the navbar isn't expanded. To fix that, we can use:

```
body 
overflow: scroll
```

As for the horizontal movement, we can fix it by adding a top value for the menu button :

```
top: 1.3rem
```

here's a jsfiddle link to the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/6jt4hL9v/